# Merging RDDs using Scala Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have 2 RDDs.

```
RDD1: ((String, String), Int)
RDD2: (String, Int)
```

For example:

```
    RDD1

    ((A, X), 1)
    ((B, X), 2)
    ((A, Y), 2)
    ((C, Y), 3)

    RDD2

    (A, 6)
    (B, 7)
    (C, 8)

Output Expected

    ((A, X), 6)
    ((B, X), 14)
    ((A, Y), 12)
    ((C, Y), 24)
```

In RDD1, (String, String) combination is unique and in RDD2, every string key is unique.
The score of A from RDD2 (6) gets multiplied with all the score values of entries that have A in its key in RDD1.

```
14 = 7 * 2
12 = 6 * 2
24 = 8 * 3
```

I wrote the following but gives me an error on case:

```
val finalRdd = countRdd.join(countfileRdd).map(case (k, (ls, rs)) => (k, (ls * rs)))
```

Can someone help me out on this ?

Comment: I guess that `(A, X),6` should be `(A, X),12` following your logic, or did I miss something?

Comment: It is 6 because value of A in RDD2 is 6 and in RDD1, (A,X) has a value of 1. So they multiply to give 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first RDD doesn't have the same key type as the second RDD(tuple (A, X) versus A). You should transform it before joining:

```
val rdd1  = sc.parallelize(List((("A", "X"), 1), (("A", "Y"), 2)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List(("A", 6)))
val rdd1Transformed = rdd1.map { 
   case ((letter, coord), value) => (letter, (coord, value)) 
}
val result = rdd1Transformed
  .join(rdd2)
  .map { 
    case (letter, ((coord, v1), v2)) => ((letter, coord), v1 * v2) 
  }
result.collect()
res1: Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((A,X),6), ((A,Y),12))
```